# Application hangs on clicking "Choose" button in IKPictureTaker view

Tags: objective-c, macos, ikpicturetaker

I am facing a strange hang issue with IKPictureTaker and on clicking a "Choose" button. I am doing below operation using IKPictureTaker.

1. When a user wants to change a profile picture, upon clicking "Change Image" button, I display a IKPictureTaker view along with "Choose" button by setting IKPictureTakerAllowsFileChoosingKey to YES.
2. First time on clicking the "Choose" button, open panel will be displayed allowing user to select an image of his choice.
3. Next, on clicking the "Set" button, internally I am calling a profile picture upload function of a server in a separate thread and everything works great.
4. Next if the user tries to do the operation 1) and 2) again application hangs on clicking the "Choose" button.
5. After investigation I found that this issue is something to do with the background upload operation I am doing with the server.Because if I comment the upload part of code everything looks good.
6. I don't see any issues with the upload operation performed in the separate thread and it gives up it s runloop once it is done with its upload operation and all UI related operations again taken care in the main thread.
7. Application hangs only if I click on the "Choose" button. If I select the recent pictures or take a new photo using the camera everything works great.

Is there anyone who faced the same issue? Is it something to do with the NSOpenPanel displayed when we click on the "Choose" button?

Comment: debugger pause shows main thread is waiting for __semwait_signal (). Any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Comment: You should accept answers to your other questions, it will make others more inclined to help you.